# Do integration/differentiation processes work as simple filters?

Tags: filtering, digital

How these processes are different from simple IIR 1 order filtering, FIR filters in terms of amplitude and phase characteristics?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, integration and differentiation can be linear filters.
You can start from `laplace properties` that say:

$ \int_{0}^{t} {x(t)dt} \longrightarrow \frac{X(s)}{s} \\ \frac{d}{dt}x(t) \longrightarrow sX(s) $

So you can find `transfer function` of integration and differentiation:

$ H_{INT}(s) = \frac{1}{s} \\ H_{DIFF}(s)=s $

You can convert these transfer function in digital `IIR` filters for example by `bilinear transform` or others digitization techniques. However you should notice that $ H_{DIFF}(s) $ is not causal, then you must add a `pole` to the transfer faction far from `useful` signal frequency, and it begin:

$ H_{DIFF_{causal}}(s)= \frac{s}{\alpha s + 1}$ where $\alpha$ is the `time constant of the derivative filter` a small `real` $>0$.

Using `bilinear transform` $H_{INT}(z)$ begin a `trapezoidal integrator`, using `Euler transofrm` $H_{INT}(z)$ begin a `rectangular integrator`, you can see this difference and the digitization in the [MATLAB PID page](https://it.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pid.html).

I wrote a [simple `PID` program](https://github.com/andrea993/SimplePID) in `C` that computes these operations using `Euler transform`, a `PID` in closed loop doesn't need to be accurate so `Euler` works well.

In literature there are a lot of ways to implement `derivative` filters (`IIR` and `FIR`) that workaround in elegant way anti-causal problem, however in a lot of situations you can simply digitize the analog transfer functions to make IIRs and FIRs.